# Disabling the Find/Find Next options in a FindReplace dialog

Tags: winapi, mfc

When using the ::ReplaceText() Win32 api function, is it possible to disable or hide the find/find next buttons, leaving only the Replace?

If not I will need to roll my own dialog.

Comment: My advice: simply don't use those dialogs, IMO they are just good for Notepad. Make your own which is much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReplaceText()` dialog allows you to hide the `direction`, `Match case`, and `Match Whole Word` boxes using the various `FR_HIDE...` flags, but it does not have any flags for hiding the `Find Next` and `Replace` buttons.  So you will have to do it manually.

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can create a custom dialog resource that contains just the UI fields you want to display, and then you can enable the `FR_ENABLETEMPLATE` or `FR_ENABLETEMPLATEHANDLE` flag and provide the dialog as a template in the `lpTemplateName` or `hInstance` field, respectively.
2. You can enable the `FR_ENABLEHOOK` flag and provide a `lpfnHook` callback that disables/hides the existing buttons in the default dialog when processing the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

These techniques are described in the MSDN documentation:

[Customizing the Find or Replace Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646956.aspx#_win32_Customizing_the_Find_or_Replace_Dialog_Box)

I would opt for #2, as it is easy to implement in code, eg:

```
UINT_PTR CALLBACK FRHookProc(HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uiMsg == WM_INITDIALOG)
    {
        HWND hBtn = GetDlgItem(hdlg, 1); // The "Find Next" button is ID 1
        if (hBtn)
            ShowWindow(hBtn, SW_HIDE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
FINDREPLACE fr = {sizeof(fr), 0};
...
fr.Flags = FR_ENABLEHOOK;
fr.lpfnHook = &FRHookProc;
...

HWND hDlg = ReplaceText(&fr);
```

Comment: I just tried this and ran into a problem - if I specify a Hook function, then the find replace dialog does not get drawn properly, and the application freezes. This is true even if the hook function does nothing but return TRUE. Did you ever encounter this?

Comment: @TomDavies no. And I tested the code before I posted it, it worked fine. But read the documentation: "*If the hook procedure returns zero, the default dialog box procedure processes the message.
**If the hook procedure returns a nonzero value, the default dialog box procedure ignores the message**.*"

Comment: Yeah, read all the docs (what docs there are - there's very little out there about this). Couldn't get it to work, so went with the template solution, which for me was easier. Thanks.